# JAVA Lambda Expression with two list - inner join

Tags: java, lambda

My code:

```
public class Country {
        private final Integer countryId; // PK, primary key
        private final String name;

        public Country(Integer countryId, String name) {
            this.countryId = countryId;
            this.name = name;
        }
        // omitting getters
    }

    public class State {
        private final Integer stateId;   // PK
        private final Integer countryId; // FK, foreign key
        private final String name;

        public State(Integer stateId, Integer countryId, String name) {
            this.stateId = stateId;
            this.countryId = countryId;
            this.name = name;
        }
        // omitting getters
    }
     public class City {
        private final Integer cityId;    // PK
        private final Integer stateId;   // FK
        private final String name;

        public Integer getCityId() {
            return cityId;
        }

        public Integer getStateId() {
            return stateId;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public City(Integer cityId, Integer stateId, String name) {
            this.cityId = cityId;
            this.stateId = stateId;
            this.name = name;
        }
        // omitting getters
    }



    public static void main(String[] args){
        Set<Country> countries = Collections.singleton(new Country(1, "India"));
        Set<State> states = Collections.singleton(new State(1, 1, "Maharastra"));
        Set<City> cities = Collections.singleton(new City(500, 30, "sangai"));
    }
```

Using Lambda Expression java, need the output like `CountryName`, `StateName`, `CityName` having inner join on the keys of `countryId`, `stateID`, `cityID`.

Comment: It's not clear what are you looking for?

Comment: Thanks for cheking.. I have three List<City> , List<State>, List<Country>. Using lambda express, how can i join all the three list using join on stateID of ListCity & ListState and join on countryID of ListState & List Country. And finally fetching the value of Country Name, State Name, City Name.

Comment: Dont put such information into comments. Always update your question instead. You really want that the people reading your question understand what it will be about. So put such context right in the beginning of the question.

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: What did you try yourself, what worked, what didn’t. You talk about joins if it’s data from a database you will be better of doing it in the database instead of in Java

Comment: Thanks martin. I need in java. I am able to achieve this in C# and SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Smth. like this:

```
public final class Country {

    private final int countryId;
    private final String name;

    public Country(int countryId, String name) {
        this.countryId = countryId;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public final class State {

    private final int stateId;
    private final int countryId;
    private final String name;

    public State(int stateId, int countryId, String name) {
        this.stateId = stateId;
        this.countryId = countryId;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public final class City {

    private final int cityId;
    private final int stateId;
    private final String name;

    public City(int cityId, int stateId, String name) {
        this.cityId = cityId;
        this.stateId = stateId;
        this.name = name;
    }

}

public static void main(String... args) {
    Set<Country> countries = Collections.singleton(new Country(1, "India"));
    Set<State> states = Collections.singleton(new State(1, 1, "Maharastra"));
    Set<City> cities = Collections.singleton(new City(500, 30, "sangai"));

    Map<Integer, List<State>> countryIdState = states.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(State::getCountryId));
    Map<Integer, List<City>> stateIdCity = cities.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(City::getStateId));

    final class Record {

        private final String country;
        private final String state;
        private final String city;

        public Record(String country, String state, String city) {
            this.country = country;
            this.state = state;
            this.city = city;
        }
    }

    List<Record> records =
            countries.stream()
                     .filter(country -> countryIdState.containsKey(country.getCountryId()))
                     .map(country -> countryIdState.get(country.getCountryId()).stream()
                                                   .filter(state -> stateIdCity.containsKey(state.getStateId()))
                                                   .map(state -> stateIdCity.get(state.getStateId()).stream()
                                                                            .map(city -> new Record(country.getName(), state.getName(), city.getName()))
                                                                            .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                                                   .flatMap(List::stream)
                                                   .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                     .flatMap(List::stream)
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());

    // use records
}
```